# How to setup DXA on Local machine

Tags: dxa, tridion-sites

How can we install DXA on the local machine using .NET and connect to the tridion site on the remote device?

Also, I want to configure DXA with already created publications.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It’s a bit old, but may be a good start: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/using-and-debugging-dxa-with-web-8-5-on-amazon

Comment: Thanks @NunoLinhares after following the article Its show

"ERROR - Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: No View Model registered for View 'Sdldemo:Page:GeneralPage'. Check that you have registered this View in the 'Sdldemo' area registration.
   at Sdl.Web.Common.Models.ModelTypeRegistry.GetViewModelType(MvcData viewData)"  in the logs

Comment: Hi @Sneh Gour, what is your expectation? are you looking for debugging setup with DXA Framework, or looking to prepare the new web app + core module for development perspective?

Comment: Hi @Velmurugan I've publication in my cm and I'm trying to setup DXA on that publication. We've done almost everything for DXA on our Local machine but we're stuck on ViewModel configuration

Comment: Looks like you are using the **Sdldemo** custom module. In that case, you can override this on web.config <add key="default-module" value="Sdldemo" />, or insure that template metadata module name parameter value to Sdldemo. Ensure that you have installed custom module DLLs and Areas and Views to SiteWebapp root.

Comment: Sometimes maybe also use multiple modules, In that case, we will keep the main website functionality module to web.config and other modules to ensure the module name is passed from the CT metadata itself.

Answer (score 2):

For Setting up a new DXA ASP.NET MVC web application, you can follow the [DXA documentation](https://docs.rws.com/784837/203885/sdl-digital-experience-accelerator-2-2/setting-up-a-new-asp-net-mvc-web-application).

In case you are looking to set up [debugging with DXA Framework](https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2020/04/27/tds-event-presentation-dxa-2-2-net-dynamic-documentation-module-sdl-tridion-docs-14-dxd-11-1/) then you can follow my blog it's done for Dynamic Documentation Module instead you can use either the OOTB Core module or your custom module, and skip the search module if it's not applicable to you.

I hope it helps